# Understanding the size of virtual derived class

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, memory-layout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
  int a;
};
class B1 : virtual public A {
  int b1;
};
class B2 : virtual public A {
  int b2;
};
class C : public B1, public B2 {
  int c;
};

int main() {
  A obj1; B1 obj2; B2 obj3; C obj4;
  cout << sizeof(obj1) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(obj2) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(obj3) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(obj4) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
16
16
40
```

In the above c++ program,
size of A is 4 because it has only one int
size of B1 is 16 because (int+ int + virtual pointer) same for B2

But how come the size of C is 40???

Comment: There can be alignment and padding

Comment: @drescherjm Everything's an `int`. What's there to align or pad?

Comment: @Spencer Probably this is x64 architecture, so `vptr` is 8 bytes.

Comment: I expect you may not see this if int was the same size as a ptr.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Then the size would be 44, no?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think you have the correct idea with the added `vptr` assuming 32-bit architecture.  The linked question doesn't appear to address the vptr in virtual inheritance, so maybe you should post an answer here.

Comment: FWIW, there no reason to really understand this unless you are interested in writing your own compiler.  The mechanics of how polymorphism works in C++ is left up to the implementation, so every compiler vendor might do this differently.

Comment: 16 + 16 + vptr looks = 40?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili 16+16+4+vptr. Remember `A` also has an `int`.

Comment: @Spencer vptr is likely 8 bytes.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili See above comment.

Comment: *But how come the size of C is 40???* -- It's really funny when programmers can't believe the compiler may actually be right when it returns `sizeof()` that doesn't meet their expectations.  Like "hey, you're not supposed to give me that answer."

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  It's a common beginner error.

Comment: 40 = 16 + 16 + `sizeof(int)` + padding to multiple of 8 for the alignment requirement of pointers.

Comment: Raj: Let us know whether you're compiling with 32 or 64 bit, and also what you get when you compile with the other architecture.

Comment: Here is the code fixed and shows the size of a pointer: [https://ideone.com/JFy4Om](https://ideone.com/JFy4Om)

Comment: Please describe your arch, notably print `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result may differ depending on the compiler you are using and the system architecture. For example, `msvc 19.28 x64` gives this self-explanatory result (use the option `/d1reportAllClassLayout` to get it):

```
class C size(44):
    +---
 0  | +--- (base class B1)
 0  | | {vbptr}
 8  | | b1
    | | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | +---
16  | +--- (base class B2)
16  | | {vbptr}
24  | | b2
    | | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | +---
32  | c
    | <alignment member> (size=4)
    +---
    +--- (virtual base A)
40  | a
    +---
```

But for `msvc 19.28 x86` the result would be:

```
class C size(24):
    +---
 0  | +--- (base class B1)
 0  | | {vbptr}
 4  | | b1
    | +---
 8  | +--- (base class B2)
 8  | | {vbptr}
12  | | b2
    | +---
16  | c
    +---
    +--- (virtual base A)
20  | a
    +---
```

#### Update

It should be noted that the class layout above clearly demonstrates the feature of virtual inheritance, in which only one copy of a base class instance (`A`) are inherited by grandchild derived class (`C`). If the `A::a` data member were public, we could use the following statements inside member function of class `C`:

```
void C::foo() {
    B2::a = 1;
    B1::a = 2;
    std::cout << B2::a << " " << B1::a << " " << A::a; // Output: 2 2 2
}
```

But if you do not use virtual inheritance (but just public), then the class `C` layout will be like this:

```
class C size(20):
    +---
 0  | +--- (base class B1)
 0  | | +--- (base class A)
 0  | | | a
    | | +---
 4  | | b1
    | +---
 8  | +--- (base class B2)
 8  | | +--- (base class A)
 8  | | | a
    | | +---
12  | | b2
    | +---
16  | c
    +---
```

And we would have two copies of member variables of the base class `A`

```
void C::foo() {
    B2::a = 1;
    B1::a = 2;
    std::cout << B2::a << " " << B1::a; // Output: 1 2. `A::a` ambiguity error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: None of this is specified by the C++ standard, except for the fact that compiler is allowed to add padding, and I haven't actually examined any assembly code.

If compiled in GCC on x64 architecture, the structure might look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| C                                                                                                   |
| +------------------------------------+ +------------------------------------+          +----------+ |
| | B1 (16)                            | | B2 (16)                            |          | A(4)     | |
| | +--------------+ +------+ +------+ | | +--------------+ +------+ +------+ | +------+ | +------+ | |
| | |  vptr (8)    | | b1(4)| |pad(4)| | | |  vptr (8)    | | b2(4)| |pad(4)| | | c(4) | | | a(4) | | |
| | +--------------+ +------+ +------+ | | +--------------+ +------+ +------+ | +------+ | +------+ | |
| +------------------------------------+ +------------------------------------+          +----------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Checking the aligments of each structure (https://wandbox.org/permlink/a4l99p6JwTrSdWx1), we see that `A` is aligned to 4 bytes, and all the remaining structures are aligned to 8 bytes when using GCC compiler.

I assume that your computer is in x64 architecture. This means pointer must be at least 8 bytes long, and because vptr exist in `B1` and `B2`, the whole structure gets aligned to 8 bytes. Because of this, compiler needs to add padding to both structures, in order to keep `sizeof(B1) % alignof(B1) == 0` (or in simple words to keep the structure aligned).

Answer (score 3):

It's not very important to know how exactly `C` is laid out and padded since this is implementation-defined and will differ between platforms. But there is one specific detail...

Base class `A`, being virtually inherited, is extracted to the top of the hierarchy. So it's part of `B1` only for as long as `B1` is used "by itself". When it's inherited further inside `C`, `A` is no longer part of it.

That means we can't rely on `sizeof(B1)` or `sizeof(B2)`, as we have to subtract `sizeof(A)` from them first. But removing 4 bytes from `B1` won't reduce it's size from 16 to 12 since it must be aligned and padded to 8 bytes (assuming 64-bit) due to the vbptr.

So we end up with `sizeof(B1 less A)`+`sizeof(B2 less A)`+`sizeof(A)`+`sizeof(C::c)` = 16+16+4+4 = 40.

We can get some funky output if we make `A` larger:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
  int a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;
};
class B1 : virtual public A {
  int b1;
};
class B2 : virtual public A {
  int b2;
};
class C : public B1, public B2 {
  int c;
};

int main() {
  A obj1; B1 obj2; B2 obj3; C obj4;
  cout << "sizeof(A)  = " << sizeof(obj1) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(B1) = " << sizeof(obj2) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(B2) = " << sizeof(obj3) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(C)  = " << sizeof(obj4) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Prints](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ROz6kJWyKiDmcTWS):

```
sizeof(A)  = 20
sizeof(B1) = 32
sizeof(B2) = 32
sizeof(C)  = 56
```

Now it's more clear that `sizeof(C)` < `sizeof(B1)` + `sizeof(B2)`.

To know more you can [play with offsets](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wB8gSBjO0wBFEHCG) to see exactly how `C` is laid out.